# I want to check in Panda Dataframe if testsubject( "ID") has given info(datapoint) on a certain day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i'm fairly new to Python and Pandas so I'm thinking maybe this is obvious but I just don't get it.

I have a dataset that has columns "ID"s (random numbers), "Date", and a datapoint on that day "Activity"

So if I have five(or X amount of) IDs, ID : [1,2,3,4,5] and then each ID has Dates running for lets say 30 days.( The ID repeats 30 times ),

So ID 1 has dates from 2018-11-1 to 2018-11-30, and the same for 2, 3 and so on. Finally we have a column named "Activity" which may have value that is either 0 or something X > 0.

First 3 rows would be [1,2018-11-1,70], [1,2018-11-2,45], [1,2018-11-3,0]

So in other words there is a random amount of days when activity has a been recorded.

What is the easiest way to calculate the amount of occurrences (How many days activity has been logged) per ID. Or even just which id has the highest amount of ocurrences.

I was thinking that nested for loops would be the way to go, but then i realized that it's not that straight forward since I also need to check if ID is the same during every iteration and then reset it when the id changes. So a list with IDs without duplicate values maybe but this starts to feel a bit too complicated since this is a minor thing to check.

I also know that this is not probably the correct way to iterate pd.dataframe, but you get the idea about what I was thinking
`

```
IDs = [1,2,3,4,5]
i = 1
occ = [0,0,0,0,0]
for ID in IDs:
    for row in dataframe:
         if i == row[0]:
              if row[2] > 0:
                  occ[i-1] += 1
         else:
             i = i + 1
             if i == 6:
                  break
```

`

Answer (score 1):

I've created a dummy dataframe using the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
ID = [1,2,3,4,5]
Dates = ['01/05/2022', '02/03/2022', '12/03/2022', '02/03/2022', '02/04/2022']
Activity = [0, 1, 4, 5, 1]
df['ID'], df['Date'], df['Activity'] = ID, Dates, Activity
```

Giving me this dataframe:

```
ID        Date  Activity
0   1  01/05/2022         0
1   2  02/03/2022         1
2   3  12/03/2022         4
3   4  02/03/2022         5
4   5  02/04/2022         1
```

Now with the following code I am able to find the 'maximum' level of activity (User with ID 4) and take the 1st index (index 0) to give me the ID number:

```
df.loc[df['Activity'].idxmax()][0]
```

And I'm given the ID: 4, as I'd hoped for max. no of occurrences.

You could also do this:

```
print(df[['ID']][df.Activity == df.Activity.max()])
```

to achieve the same.

As a general tip - with pandas dataframes, most solutions do not require loops and iteration, hence why it is such a fast and efficient tool.